# Unable to solve python error TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have two files

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding=utf-8
import logging
import mailbox
import module
import os
import sys
from mailbox import Maildir, MaildirMessage
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
from kafka.producer.future import FutureRecordMetadata

LOG_LEVEL: logging = os.environ.get('CATCHALL_LOG_LEVEL', 'WARNING').upper()
logging.basicConfig(
    level=LOG_LEVEL,
    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s %(lineno)d: %(message)s',
    filename='/var/log/email-catcher.log'
)
logging.getLogger('kafka').setLevel(logging.WARNING)

MAILBOX_DIRECTORY: str or None = os.environ.get('CATCHALL_MAILBOX_DIRECTORY')
if not MAILBOX_DIRECTORY:
    logging.critical(
        "CATCHALL_MAILBOX_DIRECTORY env var not found. Exiting ...")
    sys.exit(1)

BACKUP_MAILBOX_DIRECTORY: str or None = os.environ.get('CATCHALL_BACKUP_MAILBOX_DIRECTORY')
if not BACKUP_MAILBOX_DIRECTORY:
    logging.critical(
        "CATCHALL_BACKUP_MAILBOX_DIRECTORY env var not found. Exiting ...")
    sys.exit(1)

KAFKA_SERVERS: str or None = os.environ.get('CATCHALL_KAFKA_SERVERS')
if not KAFKA_SERVERS:
    logging.critical("KAFKA_SERVERS_LIST env var not found. Exiting ...")
    sys.exit(1)

KAFKA_SERVERS_LIST: list = KAFKA_SERVERS.split(',')
KAFKA_TOPIC = os.environ.get('CATCHALL_KAFKA_TOPIC', 'best-booking-emails')


def put_mail_in_kafka_topic(from_address: str, mail: str, kafka_producer: KafkaProducer) -> bool:
    """
    :rtype: bool
    :param from_address: string
    :param mail: string
    :param kafka_producer: KafkaProducer
    """
    logging.debug('connected to kafka producer')
    try:
        future: FutureRecordMetadata = kafka_producer.send(
            topic=KAFKA_TOPIC,
            key=from_address.encode(),
            value=mail.encode()
        )
        future.get(timeout=60)
        return True
    except KafkaError:
        logging.exception('failed to publish mail on kafka topic')
        return False


def backup_mail(mail: mailbox.MaildirMessage) -> None:
    """
    :rtype: None
    :param mail: mailbox.MaildirMessage
    """
    backup_mbox.lock()
    try:
        backup_mbox.add(mail)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error(ex)
    finally:
        backup_mbox.flush()
        backup_mbox.unlock()


def read_mails() -> None:
    """
    :rtype: None
    """
    mbox: Maildir = mailbox.Maildir(MAILBOX_DIRECTORY)
    if not len(mbox.items()):
        logging.info('no new emails found in mbox')
        return

    processed_email_count: int = 0
    kafka_producer: KafkaProducer = KafkaProducer(
        bootstrap_servers=KAFKA_SERVERS_LIST,
        compression_type='gzip'
    )
    mbox.lock()
    try:
        item_keys_to_remove: list = []
        for key, mail in mbox.iteritems():
            logging.info(f"new mail from {mail['From']} with subject: {mail['Subject']}")

            filtered_mail: tuple[object, MaildirMessage] or None = module.filter_mail(mail, logging)
            if filtered_mail is not None:
                logging.info(f"Filtered mail from {mail['From']} with subject: {mail['Subject']}")
                if put_mail_in_kafka_topic(filtered_mail[0], filtered_mail[1].as_string(), kafka_producer):
                    item_keys_to_remove.append(key)
                    backup_mail(mail)
                    processed_email_count += 1
            else:
                logging.critical(f"Failed to filter mail or publish mail on kafka topic")

        for key in item_keys_to_remove:
            mbox.remove(key)
    finally:
        mbox.flush()
        mbox.unlock()
        mbox.close()
        kafka_producer.flush()

    logging.info(f"mail processed: {processed_email_count}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    backup_mbox: Maildir = mailbox.Maildir(BACKUP_MAILBOX_DIRECTORY)
    try:
        logging.info("Job started...")
        read_mails()
        logging.info("Job finished")
    finally:
        backup_mbox.close()
```

module.py

```
# coding=utf-8
import logging
import re
import unicodedata
from mailbox import MaildirMessage
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, ResultSet, Tag


def filter_mail(mail: MaildirMessage, log: logging) -> tuple[object, MaildirMessage] or None:
    """ Filter the mail to only include messages that have need to be sent
    :rtype: tuple[object, MaildirMessage] or None
    :param mail: MaildirMessage
    :param log: logging
    """
    try:
        parsed_email: BeautifulSoup = BeautifulSoup(mail._payload, 'html.parser')
        original_from_email_id: object = \
            re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)", mail['From'])[0]

        # Extracting the orignal mail sender
        from_element: str = parsed_email.find_all("br")[0].parent.text
        from_element = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", from_element)
        from_element = from_element.replace("\n", " ")
        from_element = from_element.replace("=2E", ".")
        emails_from: list = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)", from_element)

        # Modifing email headers
        email_subject: str = mail['Subject'].replace("Fw: ", "")
        mail.replace_header("From", emails_from[0])
        mail.replace_header("Subject", email_subject)

        # Removing html block from email content
        html_block_to_be_removed_element: ResultSet[Tag] = parsed_email.select('div[style=\'3D"margin:0\']')
        html_block_to_be_removed: str = str(html_block_to_be_removed_element).removeprefix('[').removesuffix(']')
        mail._payload = str(parsed_email).replace(html_block_to_be_removed, '')

        return original_from_email_id, mail

    except Exception as e:
        log.critical(f"Failed to Filter email, Exception Message - " + str(e))
        return None
```

I am unable to solve the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import module
  File "/Users/manav.mehta/Documents/Projects/email-catcher/module.py", line 9, in <module>
    def filter_mail(mail: MaildirMessage, log: logging) -> tuple[object, MaildirMessage] or None:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I am using python 3.8, I have tried every type hinting possible I am unable to understand what is the issue, I believe it could be because of the

> filtered_mail: tuple[object, MaildirMessage] or None = module.filter_mail(mail, logging)

and then I am using the first object as index which creating the issue.

> if put_mail_in_kafka_topic(filtered_mail[0], filtered_mail[1].as_string(), kafka_producer):

But, I am not sure what is it.
I think it could be because from the below line

> original_from_email_id: object = 
> re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z0-9.*-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.*-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)", mail['From'])[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Python version is not compatible with subscripting built-in types, which is [introduced on Python 3.9](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/).

In your case, you may replace `tuple[...]` with

```
import typing

typing.Tuple[...]
```

or just use a special import keeping your original code, [as brilliantly noted by @Taavi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721731/unable-to-solve-python-error-typeerror-type-object-is-not-subscriptable/77721756#comment137020172_77721756):

```
from __future__ import annotations

tuple[...]
```

---

Other thing is that you can't do

```
tuple[object, MaildirMessage] or None
```

Instead, you must do

```
tuple[object, MaildirMessage] | None
```

Comment: You [can](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/#implementation) use the lowercase `tuple[...]` syntax on Python 3.7+ with `from __future__ import annotations`.